# 4-d Interpolation

Tags: matlab, interpolation

I have a 500*4 matrix that reports an experimental result which depends on three other values (t,x,g). Something like this:

```
t   x   g   result
1   2   3   3
2   2   4   2
2   2   1   3
...
```

I need to create a function that return the "result" for every given tuple (t,x,g) even if it is not present in the matrix. I think that I need a 4-d interpolation but I don't know how to do it in Matlab. Can someone suggest a way to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use either TriScatteredInterp or griddata3. Both will solve your problem of interpolating data points in a scattered set. If the points do not lie inside the convex hull of the data, then those methods will still fail to extrapolate, but then no method is perfect.

Answer (score 0):

I think you actually need a 3-d interpolation as 3 points get mapped to to one (results).

That being said, look at [interpn](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/interpn.html). It's certainly what you need

Comment: No. Interpn does not work on scattered data. If all combinations are not present, as they surely are not since there are only 500 points, then this is technically scattered data, so interpn will NOT be appropriate.